# How can I branch my code in TFS, within a build definition

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild

I'm using Visual Studio Online, and looking at CI and automated deploys

My Web Test Project has three branches: DEV,UAT,LIVE

I have a build Definition that builds from the DEV branch and uses msbuild to deploy the Website to my UAT server, this works fine. What I would like to do is after the publish, branch the code from DEV to UAT

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PowerShell post test to call "tf merge" to push code from DEV to UAT.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the wrong way round. If you are promoting by quality that is a value of the build output and not the code.

A better way would be to not have branch by quality (dev->qa) but to have branch by release (1.0->2.0). Then have a single build on a version that progress through DEV->QA. This is the recommended method of controlling quality and minimises risk. The release management tools that are part of TFS and VSO use this method.

http://nakedalm.com/create-release-management-pipeline-professional-developers/

If you want to increase and control quality you will need to move away from branch by quality. It is not possible to achieve continuous delivery of any form with it.